# passing access token to backend Node.js Google Sign-in scopes

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, google-signin

Greeting fellowship of kings and queens.

I'm trying to implement user Google sign in using Google identity from https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web at the front end and using the access token from
the front end to get GDrive file using Node.js Google API at the back end https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client/blob/main/samples/accessTokenAuth.js

Unfortunately, I am not able to get the result of the user GDrive sign-in file. Below is my code.

`login.ejs` file front end

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Login</title>
    <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>
    <meta name="google-signin-client_id"
        content="168395681600-uur7hvveutnmpn7a8265e0f1omlbogau.apps.googleusercontent.com">
</head>

<body>

    <div class="g-signin2" data-onsuccess="onSignIn" data-theme="dark"></div>

    <a href="/" onclick="signOut();">Sign out</a>

    <script>
        function onSignIn(googleUser) {

            const access_token = googleUser.getAuthResponse(true).access_token
            console.log(access_token)

            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open('POST', '/login');
            xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
            xhr.send(JSON.stringify({ token: access_token }));
        }
    </script>

    <script>
        function signOut() {
            var auth2 = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();
            auth2.signOut().then(function () {
                console.log('User signed out.');
            });
        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

nodejs backend --server.js

```
const { google } = require('googleapis');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

const port = process.env.PORT || 5000

/**
 * This example demonstrates authenticating to the Google APIs backend using
 * an access token only. Generally, access tokens are obtained using the standard JWT
 * and 3-legged-OAuth methods, but from time to time only the access token
 * is available.
 * 
 * 
 */

app.use(express.json())

app.set('view engine', 'ejs')

// app.get('/', (req, res) => {
//  res.render('index')
// })


app.post('/login', (req, res) => {
    let token = req.body.token
    console.log(token)

    const runSample = async(token)=> {
        const drive = google.drive({
            version: 'v2',
            // this header will be present for every request
            headers: {
                Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
            },
        });

        // Make an authorized request to list Drive files.
        const res = await drive.files.list();
        console.log(res.data);

        return res;
    }

    if (module === require.main) {
        runSample().catch(console.error);
    }

    runSample(token)


})

app.get('/login', (req, res) => {
    res.render('login')
})



app.listen(port, () => { console.log(`listening to port:${port}`) })
```

package.json

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "ejs": "^3.1.6",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "googleapis": "^89.0.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js",
    "dev": "nodemon server.js"
  },
  "name": "google-api-nodejs-client",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "description": "",
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^2.0.14"
  }
}
```

When I tried to check the scope by `console.log(googelUser.getAuthResponse(true))` it only shows

scope:"email profile https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile openid [https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email"](https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email%22)

But I already added all the scopes at the OAuth consent screen for this Google Drive API tq...